# How to write a container with iterator? C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator, constants, containers

I was trying to write a class `SetList` and a class `iterator` inside class  `SetList` that allows forward iteration through it. Each `ListNode` will have info, next. But I'm confused with `iterator` and `const_iterator`.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// forward declare the iterator
template < class T, int N > class iterator;

// define the container, make the iterator a friend
template < class T, int N >
class SetList
{
    friend class iterator < T, N >;
    typedef iterator<T, N> iterator;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T * pointer;
    typedef T & reference;

    // define the iterator
    template < class T, int N >
    class iterator
    {
    private:
        SetList <T, N> mySetList;
        int mySize;
        int myOffset;
        int myIncrement;
    public:
        iterator( SetList & sl, int size, int in, int off)
            : mySetList( sl ), mySize ( size ), myIncrement(in), myOffset(off)
        {
        }

        T & operator*() { return mySetList[ myIncrement ]; }
        iterator & operator++() { ++myOffset; return *this; }
        iterator operator++ ( int )
        {
            iterator <T, N> clone( *this );
            ++myOffset;
            return clone;
        }

        iterator begin() { return iterator( *this, 0 ); }
        iterator end() { return iterator( *this, mySize ); }
    };

    template < class T, int N >
    class const_iterator
    {
    private:
        SetList <T, N> mySetList;
        int mySize;
        int myOffset;
        int myIncrement;
    public:
        const_iterator( SetList & sl, int size, int in, int off)
            : mySetList( sl ), mySize ( size ), myIncrement(in), myOffset(off)
        {
        }

        T & operator*() { return mySetList[ myIncrement ]; }
        const_iterator & operator++() { ++myOffset; return *this; }
        const_iterator operator++ ( int )
        {
            const_iterator <T, N> clone( *this );
            ++myOffset;
            return clone;
        }

        const_iterator begin() { return iterator( *this, 0 ); }
        const_iterator end() { return iterator( *this, mySize ); }
    };
};
```

Am I writing right in the .h file? I'm not sure about the list node in my codes, how to declare them as linked-list for iterator and container.

Comment: It's poor form posting a question like this without listing specific problems you've observed, what you expected, and some test code to reproduce.  Anyway - a few random points: the iterators are already inside the `SetList` template, so don't themselves need `template <class T, int B>`, and can internally refer directly to SetList rather than `SetList<T,N>`.  Iterators should store a reference or pointer to the `SetList` (in `mySetList`), not a by-value copy: that's very expensive.